# js html select dropdown value depends on input value

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna create select drop down list where selected value will be depends on input value. Example:
If i write 0 in `<input type='text' name='answer' id="ans" oninput="myFunction();">` than will be selected dynamically value NO.

```
<select id="abcd">
<option value="1">OK</option>
<option value="0">NO</option>    
</select>
```

My attempts

```
 function myFunction() {      
var x = document.getElementById('ocena7');      
if (x == 0)
{
 document.getElementById("abcd").selectedIndex = 2;
}}
```

Greetings

Comment: Just look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/826211

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with `var x = document.getElementById('ans');` you get the DOM element not the value of it.

You need to replace that with: `var x = document.getElementById('ans').value;`

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/826211

And for your code:

You want to use

```
var x = document.getElementById('ocena7').value;
```

if you want the value of the element. Now you're just getting a reference to the element with

```
var x = document.getElementById('ocena7');
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function myFunction() {      
var x = document.getElementById('ans').value;   
if (x == 0)
{
 document.getElementById("abcd").options[1].selected = 'selected'
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="abcd">
<option value="1" >OK</option>
<option value="0" >NO</option>    
</select> 
<input type='text' name='answer' id="ans" oninput="myFunction();">
</body>
</html>
```